# MySQL: How to list all with counting function and joining table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, count

I would like to have a output of table that having count, category and all items in the category(title) field (see link1). However, i can only show 1 results in the cateogry field. As you can see in link3, actually there are many items in the category of outlook::others. I have tried to join the table(plz see link2).

I would like to have a result like these

18 software::email::outlook::others      unread folder in outlook

18 software::email::outlook::others      her boss bb cant sync

18 software::email::outlook::others      ad account locked
.
.

I have used this mysql statement but dont work

SELECT count(*)  counts, HD_CATEGORY.NAME AS CATEGORY  FROM HD_TICKET   JOIN HD_CATEGORY ON (HD_CATEGORY.ID = HD_TICKET.HD_CATEGORY_ID)  WHERE (HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID = 1)  group by HD_CATEGORY.NAME order by counts desc limit 10

Link1 (Output of result)
http://postimg.org/image/62kjzlcvz/

Link2(Database chart)
http://postimg.org/image/hg73asnen

Link3 category with title
http://postimg.org/image/9wdn5mypd

Comment: Link3(category with title)
http://postimg.org/image/9wdn5mypd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your query, but you should probably add HD_TICKET.TITLE to the group by clause.

```
SELECT count(*)  counts
     , HD_CATEGORY.NAME AS CATEGORY
     , HD_TICKET.TITLE  
FROM HD_TICKET   
JOIN HD_CATEGORY 
    ON HD_CATEGORY.ID = HD_TICKET.HD_CATEGORY_ID  
WHERE HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID = 1  
group by HD_CATEGORY.NAME
      ,  HD_TICKET.TITLE
order by counts desc limit 10
```

Grouping by part of the select clause is invalid in most DBMS, mysql (default setting) will randomly pick one row from the group. You can prevent this by adding `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` to @@sql_mode

Comment: My crystal ball is unavailable at the moment. Could you please fill in some details? Feel free to create an sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem